# How to pass a single file path argument to a macro?

Tags: macros

I want to iterate all images in a certain directory and import each image with `\includegraphics` from within the `MainInput.tex`. The batch file `IterateFiles.bat` helps us to create a list of image names in the specified directory.

```
rem IterateFiles.bat
echo off

rem %1 represents the path (relative to the main input file) to the files to be iterated 
rem %2 represents the output file name
rem the remaining args represent the extensio of file to be iterated

set curdir=%CD%
cd %1
shift

set output=%curdir%\%1.list
copy nul %output%
shift

:loop
if "%1"=="" goto :eof
dir /b *.%1 >> %output%
shift
goto :loop
```

The current implementation of `\IterateFiles` macro takes 3 arguments. The first 2 arguments are the path (relative to the `MainInput.tex`) to the directory in which images are saved. The bad thing here is that we need to specify the same path in 2 forms:  `..\dirsep Images\dirsep` and `../Images/`.

```
% MainInput.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

{
\catcode`\^0
\catcode`\\12
^gdef^dirsep{\}
}

\newread\myfile
\newcount\TotalFiles

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IterateFiles}[3]{%
\immediate\write18{IterateFiles #1 \jobname\space #3}
\openin\myfile=\jobname.list\relax
\loop
    \read\myfile to \mydata
    \unless\ifeof\myfile
    \filename@parse{\mydata}
    \section*{\mydata}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#2\filename@base}
    \advance\TotalFiles1\relax
\repeat
\closein\myfile
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\IterateFiles{..\dirsep Images\dirsep}{../Images/}{jpg png pdf eps}

\section*{Summary}
There are \the\TotalFiles\ files in total.
\end{document}
```

My question: How to pass a single file path argument `../Images/` (as opposed two arguments) to the above macro?

Comment: Shouldn't the windows command shell also parse `../Images/`?

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Oh my ghost, Windows command shell can also parse `../Images/`. I did not know this. If you convert your comment to answer, I will accept it.

Comment: This would make your question off topic in TeX.SE ;-) In fact I'm not a windows user at all, so I don't feel confident posting an answer about windows (and I couldn't even test it). So if you did all the work, you'd better self-answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my ghost, apparently Windows command shell can also parse `../Images/`. I did not know this.

```
% MainInput.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newread\myfile
\newcount\TotalFiles

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IterateFiles}[2]{%
\immediate\write18{IterateFiles #1 \jobname\space #2}
\openin\myfile=\jobname.list\relax
\loop
    \read\myfile to \mydata
    \unless\ifeof\myfile
    \filename@parse{\mydata}
    \section*{\mydata}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1\filename@base}
    \advance\TotalFiles1\relax
\repeat
\closein\myfile
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\IterateFiles{../Images/}{jpg png pdf eps}

\section*{Summary}
There are \the\TotalFiles\ files in total.
\end{document}
```

Warning: There is a hidden bug here when using `\filenamb@base` instead of `\mydata`. If there are the same filenames with different extensions, then only one of them will be included. For more detailed solution, see [How to trim the end of line character for each line read from an external file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74008).

Answer (score 4):

Use the `xstring` package to replace `/`s with `\`s (or vice versa):

```
\StrSubstitute{../Images}{/}{\dirsep}}
```