# How to trim the end of line character for each line read from an external file?

Tags: filesystem-access

How to trim the end of line character for each line read from an external `\jobname.list` file below? Note that the real scenario does not use `filecontents` package to generate the list. I use a batch file to prepare the list. The following MWE is just for the sake of simplicity.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.list}
a.jpg
b.pdf
c.eps
d.png
\end{filecontents*}

\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newread\reader

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\advance\endlinechar \@M
\loop
    \read\reader to \x
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{../../Images/\x}%
\repeat
\advance\endlinechar -\@M
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The code above cannot be compiled because `\includegraphics` does not like the end of line charcter appended in the file path. I wasted much time to find the source of problem.

### Edit:

If the image files `a.jpg` and `b.pdf` are put in `../../Images/` then the proposed solutions no longer work. How to solve it?

I mainly use `xelatex` to accommodate 4 image formats.

Comment: Add `\begingroup\endlinechar=-1` before `\loop` and `\endgroup` after `\repeat`. Also put a space (or `\par)` after `{\x}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative approach to Herbert's is to remove the space at the end of the line, which is what TeX converts the end-line to (assuming no blank lines, of course)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.list}
example-image-a.pdf
example-grid-100x100pt.png
\end{filecontents*}

\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newread\reader

\begin{document}
\def\stripend#1 \stop{\unexpanded{#1}}
\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\loop
    \read\reader to \x
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \edef\x{%
      \unexpanded{%
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]%
       }%
       {\expandafter\stripend\x \stop}%
     }%
     \x
\repeat
\closein\reader
\end{document}
```

Comment: @GarbageCollector I've edited to expand `\x` once before using `\includegraphics`. That should I hope solve any issues (which are nothing to do with the line end: it's the way `\includegraphics` does a file search that's important).

Answer (score 6):

without grouping:

```
\newread\reader
[...]
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\advance\endlinechar \@M
\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\loop
    \read\reader to \x
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{\x}%
\repeat
\closein\reader
\advance\endlinechar -\@M
\makeatother
[...]
```

if the images are saved in another directory then use (example for images in /tmp/):

```
[...]
\edef\filename{/tmp/\x}
\unless\ifeof\reader
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{\filename}%
[...]
```

Comment: What if XeTeX is used and `\endlinechar` equals 20000? Just joking. `;-)`

Comment: defined in `latex.ltx` the main source for LaTeX: `\mathchardef\@M=10000`

Comment: see my edit, which works for me.

Comment: It does not work with xelatex/latex when we import EPS file.

Comment: LuaTeX throws an error "Invalid `\endlinechar`" if `\endlinechar` is set to a value greater than 127. Therefore it is more portable and safe to assign a negative value (-1) either in a group or with saving/restoring the previous value.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach works also when the file name in `\includegraphics` has some prefix (the problem mentioned in the question probably has to do with some setting made to `\endlinechar` in `graphics.sty`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.list}
example-image-a.jpg
example-grid-100x100pt.png
\end{filecontents*}

\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newread\reader

\begin{document}

\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\begingroup\endlinechar=-1
  \loop
    \read\reader to \x
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \edef\x{../Images/\x}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{\x}
\repeat
\endgroup
\closein\reader
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

---

Here is an `expl3` implementation

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.list}
example-image-a.jpg
example-grid-100x100pt.png
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\includefromfile}{O{} m m}
 {
  \garbcoll_include:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ior_new:N \g__garbcoll_read_ior
\cs_new_protected:Npn \garbcoll_include:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g__garbcoll_read_ior { #3 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g__garbcoll_read_ior
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #2 \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##1 } } 
    \includegraphics[ #1 ]{ \l_tmpa_tl } \par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\includefromfile
  [width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]
  {../Images/}{\jobname.list}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @GarbageCollector Yes, it does. Check the simplified version and also the `expl3` one.

Comment: It does not work with xelatex/latex when we import EPS file.

Comment: @GarbageCollector It's a problem in `xetex.def`, I believe. The `expl3` version works.