# How to use latex to include EPS images with spaces in theirs names and paths?

Tags: graphics, paths, ghostscript, ps2pdf, dvips

I have EPS image files (with spaces in their names) in a directory `../../Images space bla bla bla/`. The following MWE simulates the real scenario in a simplified way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.list}
a space.eps
b space.png
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{grffile}

\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newread\reader

\begin{document}
\def\stripend#1 \stop{\unexpanded{#1}}
\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\loop
    \read\reader to \x
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \section{\x}
    \edef\x{%
      \unexpanded{%
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]%
       }%
       {../../Images space bla bla bla/\expandafter\stripend\x \stop}%
     }%
     \x
\repeat
\closein\reader
\end{document}
```

Because I want to import all image formats and manipulate them with PSTricks, I have to use latex-dvips-ps2pdf sequence. `xelatex` is not my option because it runs much slower. Shortly speaking, the compilation fails. How to solve it?

Note that the available questions and the corresponding answers in this site do not help. I have read all, none works.

Comment: It works as is with pdflatex (if you replace .eps by an extension pdflatex knows so I think it's probably the graphicx xelatex driver that needs to use the web2c convention of using `"` to quote filenames more completely.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Have you succeeded to compile it with quotes with xetex?

Comment: No and can't delve in that far at work, left comment as a hint of someone else looking at this..

Comment: My expl3 solution to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74008/how-to-trim-the-end-of-line-character-for-each-line-read-from-an-external-file works, provided you load also the `grffile` package. I suspect that also your current code will work with that package.

Comment: @egreg: your comment works but now i change to `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ Are you sure that `dvips` accepts file names with spaces? I'm not.

Comment: @egreg: I don't know anything about the internal. :-)

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ If I try including a file with spaces in the name between quotes it's accepted by LaTeX, but causes errors to `dvips`. *Don't* use spaces for any reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\special` for dvips' EPS file support already uses quotes, e.g.:

```
PSfile="a b c/d e f.eps" llx=0 lly=0 urx=24 ury=24 rwi=240
```

However, the `graphics` package has to do much more:

- File exists?
- Without extension? Try out the extensions, given in the extension list.
- Searching via \graphicspath.
- Driver specific: `\Gread@eps` reads the PostScript file to find the bounding box.

Package `grffile` deals with the first three items, if option `space` is given.
The last item needs patching (at least until I might update `grffile`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\Gread@eps{\@inputcheck#1 }{\@inputcheck"#1"\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{a b c/d e f.eps}
\includegraphics{a b c/d e f}
\graphicspath{{a b c/}}
\includegraphics{d e f.eps}
\includegraphics{d e f}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry. Probably you forgot to update `grffile`. :-)