# Why \read adds extra space to the end of content?

Tags: external-files

I have file `foo.txt` with a single byte inside: `x`. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newread\foo
\immediate\openin\foo=foo.txt
\read\foo to \content
\immediate\closein\foo
\message{content: [\content]^^J}%
\end{document}
```

It prints in the log:

```
content: [x ]
```

Why this extra space after `x`? How to get rid of it?

Comment: you have also a line end in the file. Either use `x%` in the file, or set `\endlinechar` locally to -1 when reading.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer can you please provide full example with `\endlinechar` and I will be glad to accept it

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74008/how-to-trim-the-end-of-line-character-for-each-line-read-from-an-external-file