# Simple if statement latex

Tags: conditionals, loops

Having difficulties understanding basic latex operations
I want to use: if not (number between x and y): next iteration in loop
Can anyone help me with a simple if statement for this?

```
\newread\reader
\newcount\TotalFiles  


\makeatletter
\newcommand\IterateImages[2]{%
% #1: directory path with a trailing /
% #2: a list of file extensions: eps pdf jpg png
\immediate\write18{batch "#1" \jobname\space #2}
\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\newcounter{figurecounter}\setcounter{figurecounter}{1}
\loop
    \read\reader to \filename
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \filename@parse{\filename}
    %\section*{\filename}
    \
    \vfill
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"#1\filename@base"}
    \caption{{\bf text}
    \label{fig:item\thefigurecounter}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
    \vfill
    \
    \stepcounter{figurecounter}
    \endgraf
    \advance\TotalFiles1\relax
    \clearpage
\repeat
\closein\reader
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the pointer given in the comment by Please don't touch, at [Iterate through folder foreach picture, possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194421/iterate-through-folder-foreach-picture-possible/194429#194429), the following modifications to that MWE allow the picture range to be specified as arguments 3 and 4 to `\IterateImages`.  The logic that allows the ranging of the inserts is given by the code:

```
\ifnum\TotalFiles<#3\relax\else\ifnum\TotalFiles>#4\relax\else
  [Do something if current index is in the range #3, #4, inclusive]
\fi\fi
```

Note that the file batch.bat is provided at the referenced answer.

```
% filename.tex must be compiled with 
% pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex 
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newread\reader
\newcount\TotalFiles    
\newcount\UsedFiles

\makeatletter
\newcommand\IterateImages[4]{%
% #1: directory path with a trailing /
% #2: a list of file extensions: eps pdf jpg png
\immediate\write18{batch "#1" \jobname\space #2}
\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\loop
    \read\reader to \filename
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \filename@parse{\filename}
    \advance\TotalFiles1\relax
    \ifnum\TotalFiles<#3\relax\else\ifnum\TotalFiles>#4\relax\else
      \advance\UsedFiles1\relax
      \section*{\filename}
      \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{"#1\filename@base"}
      \end{center}
      \endgraf
    \fi\fi
    \repeat
\closein\reader
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
% ./ also works
\IterateImages{./}{png}{2}{6}

\section*{Summary}
There is(are) \the\TotalFiles\ file(s) in total.\\
Of them, \the\UsedFiles\ were employed.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: His question is based on my answer [here (click)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194429/19356)

Comment: Sorry for not providing credits @ Please don't touch. Still not completely sure how if statements work in latex but I got it working anyway.

Comment: @BigChief If you have access to Knuth's "The TeXbook," p. 209-210 gives a good description of all the different "if" contexts and how they are used: `\ifnum \ifdim \ifodd \ifvmode \ifhmode \ifmmode \ifinner \if \ifcat \ifx \ifvoid \ifeof \iftrue \iffalse \ifcase`.

Comment: hey thanks i was looking for something like that, syntax looks not that intuitive, maybe because original tex is quite old?