# How to automatically include several text documents into a LaTeX document?

Tags: input, include, automation

I have several `.txt` or `.dat` files, whose names are of the form: `dn-ddmmyyyy.txt`. For instance:

```
d0-01021989.txt
d1-21021989.txt
d2-15021994.txt
d3-12121996.txt
d4-14032014.txt
d5-22022035.txt
...many more...
```

What is the best way to include all the files without using manually `\include` for each one of them?

Is there a way to create a title (like a chapter title) for each document, as "Document N", and extract the number present in the file name, which is a date, to put it in the title?

Is there a way to do this only with TeX?

Comment: Honestly, my first thought is some sort of shell script.  I don't see any pattern that would allow TeX to predict the filename.  (I mean, you *could* have TeX count until it reaches a present file for each `dN`, but that would be terribly slow.) How are the filenames generated, if they're generated?

Comment: Which operating system do you use: Windows, MacOSX, something else? And what's the preferred sorting order: by the numer after "d", by the date string, or randomly chosen? Please advise.

Comment: @SeanAllred The filenames was generated manually.

Comment: @Mico I'm using Linux and Windows, I mean, I can compile the document through a Dropbox directory, it would be cool if I could do it without problems on both operating systems. The preferred order is by the date.

Comment: Wouldn't `yyyymmdd` be better since that would at least order your files sensibly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about a TeX only solution (I could however imagine that `lualatex` could by handy) but what I usually do is the following:

1) use a command like `dir /b *.tex > allFiles.txt?` to get a file of all the TeX files. (the `/b` suppresses everything but the file name)

2) open up Excel, paste the content of `allFiles.txt` and use string concatenation to build the include commands.

For once-only this is the most efficient solution. In cases where I regularly have to update my TeX file I'd write a short Python/Bash/Batch file.

**EDIT:**

I have found some suitable code to include via `lualatex` Lua-calls in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303174/get-list-of-directory-in-a-lua) and was able to adjust it a little. It uses `\write18` as well, so it must be used with `--shell-escape`. I am pretty sure that a Lua-only solution is possible, but this is clearly beyond my Lua-knowledge.

```
%!TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
Some text before the Lua call.

\begin{luacode}
function scandir(directory)
    local i, t, popen = 0, {}, io.popen
    for filename in popen('dir "'.. directory .. '" /b d*.tex'):lines() do
        i = i + 1
        t[i] = filename
       tex.print('\\input{includes/' .. filename .. '} from ' .. filename ..'\\clearpage')  
    end
    return t
end
scandir("C:/Users/Uwe/LuaLula/includes/")
\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution is only for Microsoft Windows users. For Linux, MAC, Unix users, you have to adapt the batch-related parts. Sorry for this inconvenience and thank you for  your cooperation.

This code below was actually also prepared several decades ago [here (click)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194429/19356). Compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape filename`. Make sure that

- the input files to be included are put in a sub directory `Sub-Dir`.
- no spaces in path are allowed (to simplify the code).

### Generic Minimal Working Example

```
% filename.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{batch.txt}
rem batch.bat
echo off

rem %1 path (relative to the main input file) to the files to be iterated 
rem %2 output file name
rem remaining args represent the extension of file to be iterated

set curdir=%CD%
cd "%~1"
shift

rem output must be enclosed with "" to allow spaces in the path
set output="%curdir%\%~1.list"

if exist %output% del %output%
copy nul %output%
shift

:loop
if "%~1"=="" goto :eof
dir /b *.%~1 >> %output%
shift
goto :loop
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{oh-my-ghost.tex}
No body no body but you!
\[
E\not = mc^2
\]
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{hahaha.tex}
PSTricks is fun!
\[
pV = nRT
\]
\end{filecontents*}


\immediate\write18{%
    del batch.bat && 
    rename batch.txt batch.bat && 
    move oh-my-ghost.tex Sub-Dir/oh-my-ghost.tex && 
    move hahaha.tex Sub-Dir/hahaha.tex
}


\newread\reader
\newcount\TotalFiles    


\makeatletter
\newcommand\IterateInputFiles[2][tex]{%
% #1: directory path with a trailing /
% #2: a list of file extensions: tex 
\immediate\write18{batch "#2" \jobname\space #1}
\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\loop
    \read\reader to \filename
    \unless\ifeof\reader
    \filename@parse{\filename}
    \section{\filename@base}% change to \chapter if you want 
    \include{"#2\filename@base"}
    \advance\TotalFiles1\relax
\repeat
\closein\reader
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\IterateInputFiles{Sub-Dir/}

\section{Summary}
There is(are) \the\TotalFiles\ file(s) in total.
\end{document}
```

### Output

The following output is the proof that I am not lying.

[image]

---

#### Multi-platform Version

```
% filename.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\newif\ifDOS
%\DOStrue
\DOSfalse

\usepackage{filecontents}
\ifDOS
\begin{filecontents*}{batch.txt}
rem batch.bat
echo off

rem %1 path (relative to the main input file) to the files to be iterated
rem %2 output file name
rem remaining args represent the extension of file to be iterated

set curdir=%CD%
cd "%~1"
shift

rem output must be enclosed with "" to allow spaces in the path
set output="%curdir%\%~1.list"

if exist %output% del %output%
copy nul %output%
shift

:loop
if "%~1"=="" goto :eof
dir /b *.%~1 >> %output%
shift
goto :loop
\end{filecontents*}
\else
\begin{filecontents*}{batch.txt}
#!/bin/bash
# bash batch.sh Sub-Dir output tex

# $1 path (relative to the main input file) to the files to be iterated
# $2 output file name
# remaining args represent the extension of file to be iterated

output="$2.list"

if [ -e "$output" ]; then
    rm "$output"
fi

for ext in ${@:3}; do
    ls "$1"/*."$ext" >> "$output"
done
# $ (to squelch bad syntax highlighting in my editor)
\end{filecontents*}
\fi

\begin{filecontents*}{oh-my-ghost.tex}
No body no body but you!
\[
E\not = mc^2
\]
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{hahaha.tex}
PSTricks is fun!
\[
pV = nRT
\]
\end{filecontents*}


\ifDOS
\immediate\write18{%
  del batch.bat &&
  rename batch.txt batch.bat &&
  move oh-my-ghost.tex Sub-Dir/oh-my-ghost.tex &&
  move hahaha.tex Sub-Dir/hahaha.tex
}
\else
\immediate\write18{%
  mv batch.txt batch.sh &&
  mkdir -p Sub-Dir &&
  mv oh-my-ghost.tex hahaha.tex Sub-Dir/
}
\fi


\newread\reader
\newcount\TotalFiles

\makeatletter
\newcommand\IterateInputFiles[2][tex]{%
% #1: directory path with a trailing /
% #2: a list of file extensions: tex
\ifDOS
\immediate\write18{batch "#2" \jobname\space #1}
\else
\immediate\write18{bash batch.sh "#2" \jobname\space #1}
\fi
\openin\reader=\jobname.list\relax
\let\filename\relax
\loop
  \read\reader to \filename
  \typeout{<<< here again}
  \unless\ifeof\reader
  \filename@parse{\filename}
  \section{\filename@base}% change to \chapter if you want
  \include{"#2\filename@base"}
  \advance\TotalFiles1\relax
\repeat
\closein\reader
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\IterateInputFiles{Sub-Dir/}

\section{Summary}
There is(are) \the\TotalFiles\ file(s) in total.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will this work on Linux and the mac also?

Comment: @Nasser: No. It is only for Windows.

Comment: You have to rewrite it, in it's current form the system call is Windows-only.

Comment: Would you be okay with me editing-in a Bash version of your script?

Comment: @SeanAllred: OK. Just append it to the bottom and prefix it with your own heading to make it clearer. :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred: You created your batch using the same name `batch.txt` as mine, is it ok?

Comment: @Ohmyghost Yes, it's just for consistency :)